# Why has the term "natural history" been used to denote the study of nature, and more recently, of life?

Tags: terminology, philosophy-of-science

The term "natural history" is a translation of the Latin phrase *historia naturalis* meaning "the story of nature". Nowadays denoting the study of life, it originally also covered astronomy.

Why has there been the notion of "story" here, even in studies that by themselves have taken the form of the classification of collections using a principally synchronic approach that has paid little attention either to changes that organisms experience during their lifetimes or to evolution?

Comment: Interesting question, might it be better over at https://hsm.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: This is two questions. SE prefers just one. I suspect the linguistic asumptions in the first question may be over-simplistic, and that question better put (after some research) to SE English Language and Usage. For the second (recent usage in astronomy) it may be better follow @gilleain suggestion.  Neither are questions of biology.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology. It may be appropriate for the History of Science and Mathematics StackExchange site.

Comment: Argh, the annoyance of button-selected "reasons". @gilleain has a point. I'm not sure which is best, but I think probably here because it's mainly about biology insofar as "natural history" mainly covers topics within biology nowadays, and even if you take something like the Natural History Museum in London, it's all about living species, biology. I do accept that you can say well at some point for a few writers the term encompassed astronomy as well, which isn't in biology, which is a fair argument. Maybe offer your thoughts, mgkrebbs, before clicking a button?

Comment: I think the question is better combined, because it could get an answer from someone who can write at length about the history of the term and it's not as if the two parts can sensibly be considered totally separately. "Why has the term 'natural history' been used recently to denote the study of life?" would obviously be about biology, @David, and equally obviously neither part of the question is principally about English language and usage - see the reference to Latin in the question.

Comment: I am afraid what is "obviously about biology" and what are valid topics for this question and answer site about biology are two different things. As an aside, I haven't ever heard the term Natural History used in a modern scientific context, and if indeed it is used today in Astronomy, that is no concern of this site. I repeat that if you want to understand the history of the word you'd be better on EL&U. There are people there who actually know how the word scientia was used in Latin, and are aware how late the word science entered the English language. Have you researched this yourself?